# How to get/set boolean elements in RenderScript Allocations?

Tags: android, renderscript, android-renderscript

I create an allocation of element type boolean in Java/Kotlin like this:

```
script._booleanAllocation =  Allocation.createTyped(rs, Type.createX(rs, Element.BOOLEAN(rs), 10))
```

I pass this allocation to the script and I want to access the cell using one of the [rsGetElementAt*](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/reference/rs_allocation_data.html#android_rs:rsGetElementAt) or [rsSetElementAt*](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/reference/rs_allocation_data.html#android_rs:rsSetElementAt) methods - but there is no boolean equivalent like `rsGetElementAt_boolean` or `rsSetElementAt_boolean`. How do I access the cells?